Projecting Google Play books onto Android televisions
I wanted to know if is possible to project (using Chromecast, or a similar technology), a Google Play book onto an Android television screen.
You could then have pinch to zoom or drag on the Android device to have everything displayed onto television.
The same goes for web pages, which could readjust to size on the television screen.
With current screen mirroring technology the screen size is just mirrored and a subset of the entire television screen is displayed, but I can't have the area enlarged and zoomed.
Also, I am not sure whether television screen resolution would be adequate, but theoretically,I think, it would.
I would like to be able to read a Google Play book on the television and control panning and zooming from my phone.
Thanks.

Depending on the phone you should be able to do this as "casting" can be done at the OS level. For example I was able to do this with a stock Pixel 6a Android 13.

From your phone, swipe down until you see the various settings tiles (WiFi, Bluetooth, etc.) See if you can find a "Screen Cast" tile with the Chromecast logo. Note you may need to edit (pencil icon) your quick setting tiles list so that it is easily available.

Tap on the "Screen Cast" tile and select the Chromecast receiver device that should be on the same WiFi access point as the phone.

Your phone screen should be shared with the TV. For reference I am using a 2nd generation Chromecast device connected to a 1080p TV.

Launch the Google Play Books app and pick the book of interest.

Rotate phone to landscape. There should be a "rotate display" button if the app hasn't auto-rotated to landscape.


Once rotated you should be viewing the book page on the TV and should be able to use normal gesture controls on your phone to zoom/pan/change page.

To leave "Screen Cast" pull down from the top again to find that Quick Setting Tile, tap it again to disable.

As this appears available at the OS level, ebook app developers don't have an incentive to add such a specific feature.
